# How do I enable a three column layout in XMonad?

Tags: xmonad, haskell

I'm a Haskell and XMonad beginner. I'm trying to set up my tiling layout to allow three side by side columns (so that I can have three simultaneous tall and thin Vim instances for coding, per workspace).

In the docs, I've found [a three-column layout function](http://xmonad.org/xmonad-docs/xmonad-contrib/XMonad-Layout-ThreeColumns.html), and even managed to import it and define a custom layout, but I'm not sure how to add it to my `layoutHook`, which already has some stuff defined from [a tutorial](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/John_Goerzen%27s_Configuration) I read, to keep my `xmobar` safe from window covering.

The relevant lines of my `xmonad.hs`:

```hs
import XMonad.Layout.ThreeColumns
threeLayout = ThreeCol 1 (3/100) (1/2)
...
main = do
    xmonad $ defaultConfig
    { manageHook = manageDocks <+> manageHook defaultConfig
    , layoutHook = avoidStruts $ layoutHook defaultConfig
    ...
```

How do I change the `layoutHook` line to keep the existing configs, while also adding my three-column tile layout?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I simply forget about default config and start defining things on my own. So going that route:

```
myLayoutHook = avoidStruts(smartBorders(ThreeColumns ||| Circle ||| Grid ||| ANY_OTHER_LAYOUT_YOU_USE)
main = do
    xmonad $ desktopConfig
        { layoutHook = myLayoutHook
        ...
```

This also has `avoidStruts`, which seems to be what you want when you say you want to keep the existing config. `smartBorders` is another nice thing that hides the border when not needed, for example when you have only one window on one screen.

Comment: Ah, I see. Looking at the [default config](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Xmonad/Config_archive/Template_xmonad.hs_%280.9%29), it is very simple. I've taken your advice, and it's working very well. Thanks!