# xfce: too high gnome-terminal after going out of maximize/full screen

Tags: xfce, gnome-terminal

I use debian (wheezy) with xfce 4.8. My laptop screen resolution is 1366x768.
I use a script to open two gnome-terminals:

```
#!/bin/bash
gnome-terminal --geometry 74x51+0+0 --working-directory="/home/nuoritoveri/mag/repo/src" &
gnome-terminal --geometry 73x51+700+0 --working-directory="/home/nuoritoveri/mag/build" &
```

Together they take approximately whole space of the laptop screen, one window on the right and one on the left.

If I maximise one of the windows (by clicking button on window bar) it gets maximised.
When I click the 'unmaximise' button it does not return to previous size.
It returns to previous width but is too high - it's too big to fit the screen.

The same is happening if instead of maximising I use `F11` to get to fullscreen and go back.

I wasn't able to reproduce this problem with gnome-terminal opened from menu and resized to the approximately the same size as the start size of the script-made windows.

Is there a way to overcome this? What should I check first?

I usually use this script to edit code on the right and compile on the left but sometimes I have to enlarge the window to see a long line in code (I don't use wrap in vim, it makes me go insane).

Comment: Constantly changing window widths for coding/compiling is the reason I moved to [Xmonad](http://xmonad.org/)....

Comment: So in Xmonad you program how the windows should be spaced? That's what I'm already trying to do - must take a look. Thanks.

Comment: In Xmonad, you specify a tiling algorithm, and the window manager respaces the windows automatically when you create or remove them. You can configure it to tile however you like. In my case, I like to use several Vim windows, side by side. So I use a three column layout, based on [this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/48679/22651). But for your problem of two windows, this is handled by default, side by side with equal spacing.

Comment: I also found the problem does not occur with Mate window manager.